# No implementation found for c++ and java on NDK

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk

Here's my `app/src/main/cpp/rtspinterface.cpp`

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <android/log.h>
#include <string>

extern "C" JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_rtsp_RtspInterface_helloWorld(
    JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz) {

   return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Hello from JNI !".c_str());
}
```

and here is `app/src/java/com/rtsp/RtspInterface.java`

```
package com.rtsp;

public class RtspInterface {

    public static native String helloWorld();

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("myRtspClient");
    }
}
```

I'm getting:

```
no implementation found for Java.lang.String.com.rtsp.RtspInterface.helloWorld() (tried Java_com_rtsp_RtspInterface_helloWorld and Java_com_rtsp_RtspInterface_helloWorld__)
```

Here is the source tree at the exact moment:

https://github.com/lucaszanella/jscam/tree/8da9d546cbf6ad7cf6551010dbb42e8117d1d72d/src/jscam/android/app/src/main

I followed the naming conventions from here https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni

I'm calling the code like this:

```
Log.v("test", RtspInterface.helloWorld());
```

Comment: This: `"Hello from JNI !".c_str()` shouldn't compile.  Please check your code compiles and matches what's posted.

Comment: @RichardCritten then I guess the entire cpp file isn't even being compiled. Doesn't putting it inside cpp guarantees it's going to be? Of there are something more I need to do?

Comment: Depends on your build system ... Android Studio, ndk-build, one of the 3rd party IDE/builders ?

Comment: @RichardCritten I added a CmakeLists and it worked. I corrected the cpp error and everything worked. Glad I did something wrong in cpp and you could see it wasn't compiling

Comment: You should post your comment as an answer.

Comment: @RichardCritten just did it. Thanls

Answer (score 3):

Turns out I completely forgot to add a CmakeLists.txt for that cpp file. It simply wasn't compiling.

I did

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

add_subdirectory("../../../../../myRtspClient/myRtspClient" myRtspClient_bin)

add_library(rtspInterface SHARED rtspInterface.cpp)

target_link_libraries(rtspInterface android log)
```

and it worked :)